# How do I print out the Max and Min of an array in Mips

Tags: arrays, assembly

I am new to mips and I want to print out the max and min of an 8 element array. I saw a question similar to mine but it was done by calling a function readArray and I want to do it without that. Here's what I have so far. I just wanna know whether what I have right now is correct and how to end the loop. Like what do I write to print the correct values

```
.data
  X: .word 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8

globl main  
.text

main:
  la $t0, X
  lw $s0, 0($t0) #Sets Max to first value in array
  move $s1, $s0  #Sets Min to first value in array
  addi $t1, $0, 0 #Sets the counter to 0
  li $t1, 0     #Index for the array

loop: 
  bge $t0, 8 EndLoop
  bgt X($t1), $s0, SetMax
  blt X($t1), $s1, SetMin
  addi $t1, $t1, 4 #Increases the index for the array
  addi $t0, $t0, 1 #Increments the counter
SetMax:
  move $s0, X($t1)
  j loop
SetMin: 
  move $s0, X($t1)
  j loop
EndLoop:
  li $v0, 1
  addi $s0, $s0, 0
  addi $si, $s1, 0
  syscall
```

Am I doing something wrong. Here is the original problem: 
  Write MIPS code to search through an array X[8] words to find the minimum and maximum values. Store the maximum in register $s0 and the minimum in $s1. Print to screen min and max.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print an integer you need `$v0` to be 1 and `$a0` to be equal to the integer you want to print.So point to the register that you have saved the value.

`li $v0 1
 la $a0 ($s0)
 syscall`

the same process for $s1 .

To end the program:

`li $v0 10
 syscall`

You may want to make it more visible so print a space or tab between them. [Link](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/secondyear/spim/node8.html) with some system calls

Comment: Thanks for the help on how to end the loop. Now is there anything wrong with the syntax or anything. I just want to know what you think or if you see something wrong with the code.

Comment: Well everything seems fine, if you are getting the results you want then you only have to remove the two `addi` at the end. You don't need them.